# Smart Array P420i controller replacement

Tags: raid, hp, hp-proliant, hp-smart-array

I have two identical servers with Smart Array P420i 
One server has 4 physical drives, which form 2 logical drives (2 + 2 raid 1)
Second server also has its raid configuration with two physical drives (one logical drive, raid 1)
I put  4 drives from server one to free slots in server two and see

logicaldrive 1 (1.8 TB, RAID 1, OK)

```
  physicaldrive 1I:1:1 (port 1I:box 1:bay 1, Solid State SATA, 2 TB, OK)
  physicaldrive 1I:1:2 (port 1I:box 1:bay 2, Solid State SATA, 2 TB, OK)
```

unassigned

```
  physicaldrive 1I:1:3 (port 1I:box 1:bay 3, Solid State SATA, 1 TB, OK)
  physicaldrive 1I:1:4 (port 1I:box 1:bay 4, Solid State SATA, 1 TB, OK)
  physicaldrive 2I:0:5 (port 2I:box 0:bay 5, Solid State SATA, 500 GB, OK)
  physicaldrive 2I:0:6 (port 2I:box 0:bay 6, Solid State SATA, 500 GB, OK)
```

So, my controller sees drives, but set them as unassigned though they formed logical drives in the same controller on other server.

Can I somehow save my data and make current server to recognize existent logical drives.

Comment: Did you keep the drives together and in the same order? What does the array setup look like on the original server? Also, did you move one Logical Drive at a time?

Comment: i am not sure about order. physical slots are not the same as in first server.

Answer (score 3):

- Why did you move the drives?
- Did you keep the drives together and in the same order?
- What does the array setup look like on the original server?
- Did you move one Logical Drive at a time?

HPE has specific guidelines for this outlined at:
 https://support.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-a00020470en_us#N10166

If you missed some of these steps, all bets are off :(

[image]